# Call to a member function on null in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function check_main_module() on null on line 390

I have added a constructor and in the config, I have added modules as the library also.

```
function is_main_module_enabled($module) {
    $result = $this->Modules_model->check_main_module($module);
    return $result;
}

**`In Modules_model.php`**

function check_main_module($module) {
    $this->load->library('ptmodules');
    return $this->ptmodules->is_main_module_enabled($module);
}

**`In ptmodules file`**
function is_main_module_enabled($module) {
    $this->_ci->db->select('page_id');
    $this->_ci->db->where('page_status', 'Yes');
    $this->_ci->db->where('page_slug', $module);
    $rows = $this->_ci->db->get('pt_cms')->num_rows();
    if ($rows > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? can you explain?

Comment: Please include the class `ptmodules` code on this dicussion.

Comment: I want to call the check_main_module() method from my first function. But it is saying some null error.

Comment: did you load the Modules_model before calling it?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes in Modules_model I have used $this->load->database()

Comment: @M.Hemant if i use $this->load->model('Modules_model') in my main file then also this issue is coming

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

---

**Controller:**

```
function is_main_module_enabled($module) {
    $this->load->model('Modules_model');
    $result = $this->Modules_model->check_main_module($module);
    return $result;
}
```

**Library:**

```
function is_main_module_enabled($module) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('page_id');
    $CI->db->from('pt_cms');
    $CI->db->where('page_status', 'Yes');
    $CI->db->where('page_slug', $module);
    $rows = $CI->db->get();
    if ($rows->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with small case instead of same model name

```
$result = $this->modules_model->check_main_module($module);
```